# Lightweight Tool for Querying XML

Tags: xml

I am looking for a lightweight application to query an XML file that I have without having to resort to a programmatic interface.

Comment: Are you interested in looking through the contents of xml or are you looking for an application that can search in the xml?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found xgrep: http://www.wohlberg.net/public/software/xml/xgrep/ , it is simple and suffices for my needs.

Answer (score 0):

[XQuery](http://www.w3schools.com/xquery/default.asp) or XSLT/XPath strikes to me as the simple solution but the nature of your application determines whether we need programming interface or not and also which option to choose.